# Removing elements just won't work with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an autogenerated layout looking like this created by the jQuery.PrettyTextDiff-plugin:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/jaascript" src="the jquery library"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="diff">
        <span>
            <br/>
        </span>
        Continuing layout...
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="diff_match_patch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.pretty-text-diff.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.diff span:first-child').remove(); // As of my last try
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I wish to remove the first span inside the 'diff'-layout in runtime but I can't get it to work. I've tried several solutions found here at SO after a thorough research.

```
$('.diff').closest('span').remove();
$('.diff span').first().remove(); //recommended solution by the jQuery Foundation - yet it won't work
$('.diff span').remove();
$('.diff').find('span:gt(0)').remove();
```

Nothing seems to remove the span. How should I do to remove it?

Comment: Did you have a look at the javascript console with firebug or something similar? Is there any error message?

Comment: There are no errors with firebug. But it's reasonable to believe as one person noted below that I must move the remove event. I might be trying to remove it before it's been instantiated. That would be... Embarrassing. ;)

Comment: Okay - I tried moving the script to the end of the page - still no effect...

Comment: It might be helpful to know the exact context, where you apply the remove function.

Comment: I've updated the code above to better show the setup.

Comment: The answers really should work but have you tried adding a delay to your code to confirm it's not trying too early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere I saw a rapid comment suggesting that I could use CSS to solve this - so I did. It works as a charm.

```
.diff span {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you wrapp your jQuery code like:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.diff span').remove();
    });
```

this should work.

UPDATE: 
To remove only the first child do:

```
$('.diff span:first-child').remove();
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/stefan_wave/mLr68acm/)

Comment: And you included the jQuery libary??

Comment: So there must be a nother issue caus this should realy work see added fiddle in my post!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this…

```
$('.diff').each(function(){
   $(this).find('span').eq(0).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The statements you have provided should work:

```
$(".diff").remove("span");
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pbgqy/107/)

I believe that the code you're talking about is generated dynamically. You need to wait until is rendered and remove the span tags after it.

You could also fix the problem in the plugin itself, or ask the author of the library to fix the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

try with this`$(".diff").find("span").html("");`

Click [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wszlD).